# How to properly paint in WM_PAINT with GDI+

Tags: c++, drawing, gdi+

I'm new to using GDI+ and I was wondering how to fix the mess of creating and disposing objects that I have. Right now all the program needs to do is handle repeated `WM_PAINT` messages and update a `DrawPie` with increased degrees each time.

I have called `GdiplusStartup( &gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL );` when the window starts up, and `GdiplusShutdown( gdiplusToken );` on `WM_DESTROY`.

Degrees global variable defined near the top:

`volatile double degrees = 0;`

Here is my `WM_PAINT`:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );

    Graphics g( hdc );
    Pen p( Color::Green );
    if ( degrees > 0 ) {
        if ( degrees == 360 ) {
            g.DrawEllipse( &p, 0, 0, 100, 100 );
        } else {
            g.DrawPie( &p, 0, 0, 100, 100, -90, degrees );
        }
    }

    EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
    break;
}
```

And here is the function that updates the degrees and updates the window (It's in a separate thread):

```
void UpdateDegrees() {
    for ( ;; ) {
        if ( globalHWND != NULL ) {
            degrees += 0.1;
            InvalidateRect( globalHWND, NULL, TRUE );
            UpdateWindow( globalHWND );
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it I get a "solid" pie shape like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMRjt.png), which I assume is it just redrawing itself at every angle. It needs to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNVbY.png), in other words, clear the graphic before it redraws itself each time. (Sorry, I guess I need 10 rep to post inline images)

I know that I didn't initialize and/or dispose of my graphics correctly, but I honestly have no idea how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Never do this from a worker thread, painting is not thread-safe.  If an animation is intended then use SetTimer(), picking an interval of 15 or 31 and just call InvalidateRect().  Calculate an appropriate angle increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can do this, the standard one being to handle the [WM_ERASEBKGND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

For simplicity, you can just fill a white rectangle across the clip rect (which is specified in ps), which will clear the background being painted.

```
SolidBrush backGroundBrush(Color(255,255,255));
Rect clipRect(ps->rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, ps->rcPaint.right - ps->rcPaint.left, ps->rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top);
g.FillRectangle(&backgroundBrush, Rect(ps->rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint));
```